# How to set an Alarm in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

I know this question has asked many times on *StackOverflow* but i couldn't able to set alarm in my app because i am very new to iOS? I am following this tutorial to set an alarm:

[**Setting a reminder using UILocalNotification in iOS.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/)

However, it doesn't seems to be working for me.

I am in need to set alarm daily lets say `5.00 PM` daily. I can't use date picker for choosing the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First on your `xib`, (or code) set the date picker mode: Time (Default is date & time)
2. The system assumes that the firedate is the current date, and the time is the time the user have chosen. This is not a problem because you set a repeat interval so it will work. I have tested it.

   ```
   UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   [localNotif setFireDate:datePicker.date];
   [localNotif setRepeatInterval:NSDayCalendarUnit];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
   ```

PS: It would be a good idea to set the seconds to `0` using `NSDateComponents` class so as to set the alarm to ring at the first second of the minute you want. You can check the:

[**Local notifications in iOS.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/)

tutorial you posted on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i managed to do it different method.. Its working. One question.. Is that possible to popup custom notification view instead of default one and also would like to add custom sound which added in my project is that possible.. +1 for your support

Comment: You cannot display custom notification popup. You can add a custom sound but it should be in the application bundle. So it is impossible to play a sound that the app has downloaded from the internet. You can only play system sounds, or sounds that you have imported to your application before compile. Your welcome. Please accept the answer if you think its correct, so as to help future users find the solution to this problem.

Comment: yeah. thats what i am looking for could you able to post some codes for playing the sound in application bundle which imported before compilation please

Comment: [localNotif setSoundName:@"mymusic.m4a"]; You should drag and drop the file mymusic.m4a to your application folder. If you want to play the sound when the app is open try using AVAudioPlayer

Comment: NSURL *file = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"morning_alarm" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

Comment: Hi ,I tried to play audio file using AudioPlayer but it returns error like `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)Any IDea
`

Comment: Note, `NSDayCalendarUnit` is deprecated in IOS 8. Use `NSCalendarUnitDay` instead

Comment: Will this approach play the sound even if the device is on silent mode? How to override it? I need an approach for the user to program alarms on my app, but they want it to work when device is muted.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (void)addLocalNotification:(int)year:(int)month:(int)day:(int)hours:(int)minutes:(int)seconds:(NSString*)alertSoundName:(NSString*)alertBody:(NSString*)actionButtonTitle:(NSString*)notificationID
```

Call this method with parameters and use this

```
 + (void)addLocalNotification:(int)year:(int)month:(int)day:(int)hours:(int)minutes:(int)seconds:(NSString*)alertSoundName:(NSString*)alertBody:(NSString*)actionButtonTitle:(NSString*)notificationID {
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

//set the notification date/time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:day];

[dateComps setMonth:month];

[dateComps setYear:year];
[dateComps setHour:hours];

[dateComps setMinute:minutes];
[dateComps setSecond:seconds];

NSDate *notificationDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = notificationDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// Set notification message
localNotif.alertBody = alertBody;
// Title for the action button
localNotif.alertAction = actionButtonTitle;

localNotif.soundName = (alertSoundName == nil) ? UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName : alertSoundName;

//use custom sound name or default one - look here to find out more: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13

localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1; //increases the icon badge number

// Custom data - we're using them to identify the notification. comes in handy, in case we want to delete a specific one later
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:notificationID forKey:notificationID];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the style of the date picker to allow changing the time in addition to just the date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..Is it possible to post any tutorial for setting the alarm

Comment: The original tutorial expects that you already have some experience in this environment, and for good reason: in any tutorial on that level or more advanced, there are many basic things you could trip over. I suggest that you brush up on the basics and work your way up to these kinds of tasks, otherwise you won't be able to get anything done, change it to your liking or fix it if it breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. actually the alarm get notified but i couldn't get the popup window.. what will be the problem

Comment: Can you plain explain what exactly is your problem? I think i can help you

Comment: @GeorgeSachin I need to set alarm daily based on user timing as like in the alarm app with out date.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UILocalNotification *todolistLocalNotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[todolistLocalNotification setFireDate:[lodatepicker date]];
[todolistLocalNotification setAlertAction:@"Note list"];
[todolistLocalNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[todolistLocalNotification setAlertBody:text_todolist];
[todolistLocalNotification setHasAction:YES];
```