# How can I set a UIAlertView to execute on a predefined basis from the time or NSDate?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Im fairly new to iOS programmming and Im writing an app that requires the user to do something at predefined times. I'd like to do this with a UIAlertView much like the alarm clock app. 
How would I go about doing this? Are there methods to make the alert fire whilst the app is closed etc?

Also I'd like the user to input their preferred times using a UIPickerView in the settings. Im ok with the code for the picker views etc, but what class would I use to populate the view with times? Is it manually ie columns 1-12/0-59/(am-pm). I've been using NSDate for other options but the day/date is irrelevant in this case. Is there a time-specific class available for this?

Hope this isn't a stupid question!! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You'd probably use a local notification, though it won't be able to throw up a alert while the app is closed, only increment the "badge" number on the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [`UIDatePicker`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) in one of its `datePickerModes` instead of a stock `UIPickerView`.

iOS doesn't provide a way to make a modal alert like the built-in alarm app does. Instead, you'll want to use [Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) with a sound to implement the actual alarm. This will show an alert or banner depending on the user's Notification Center preferences and the iOS version (though it'll be a banner by default on all modern iOS versions.)

See [How to set an Alarm in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849790/how-to-set-alarm-in-ios) for specific details about setting a local alarm.