# UILocalNotification : set iOS Alarm doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to set an alarm in **iOS** app.

I tried this according to [How to set an Alarm in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849790/how-to-set-an-alarm-in-ios). Here is my main code :

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        [localNotif setFireDate:self.datePicker.date];
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        NSLog(@"fireDate %@", localNotif.fireDate);
        NSLog(@"datepicker %@", self.datePicker.date);

        [localNotif setRepeatInterval:0];
        localNotif.alertBody = @"some text";
        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotif.alertAction = @"...";

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

And I also found that : in **iOS8**,

> In iOS 8.0 and later, your application must register for user
>   notifications using -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]
>   before being able to schedule and present UILocalNotifications

So, I add the flowing in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
        UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    }
```

To my disappointed, when the fire date came, nothing happened. Did I miss other important code ?

Comment: and the **NSLog(@"current notification setting : %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]);** did print the notification settings.

Comment: How did you test? Was the app open? Have you implemented app delegate methods for LN with logging?

Comment: I test it on my iPhone and this app is always in the font-ground.

Comment: by the way, what is **LN** ?

Comment: LN is local notification. What about the app delegate methods?

Answer (score 3):

Local notifications are only displayed by iOS when the application is closed. If the application is open you need to implement the app delegate methods to receive local notification details and display the event yourself.