# is there a way to set the system timer in swift

Tags: ios, timer, alarms

using Xcode- and swift. I can't find anything at all in any search. I'm looking to set the system-level timer. I already know how to do NStimer... that's not what I need. I just need to be able to set the system timer. Also, I've already been successful in setting something on my system calendar with an alarm, but I don't want to clutter up the calendar ... Also, I don't mind doing a system alarm, that would work as well. The alarms and timers within the app only happen when the app is running in foreground. I'm looking for more of the same as when I tell siri "set my timer for 52 minutes". I mostly like the alarm because it makes the user acknowledge the alarm... whereas a reminder is definitely less passive and only "knocks" once... system alarms and timers go on forever until the user dismisses it. That's what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set an Alarm in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849790/how-to-set-an-alarm-in-ios)

Comment: The best you can do is a local notification as in the answers that @nhgrif linked to.  You can't access the system alarms or timers