# Play Alarm Sound when app is not running IOS

Tags: ios, audio, notifications, alarm

I have been working on IOS alarm app. Where i will create an alarm in the app. So i need the alarm to work as "Clock" app work in IOS.

When the alarm time reaches and the app is not running. The alarm sound will play and user can stop it by clicking Cancel or snooze..

Comment: Use local notifications and launch appropriate controller on the tap of the notification so that user can either snooze or cancel the alarm.

Comment: The first thing how i will schedule alarm?

Comment: You can't schedule an alarm as such. You will schedule a UILocalNotification.

Comment: A detailed tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/). You will find many posts on SO related to this Question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set an Alarm in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849790/how-to-set-an-alarm-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the alarm you need to use `UILocalNotification` You can set schedule for alarm withing the app like following:

```
- (void)scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate {
  UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

  [localNotification setFireDate:fireDate];
  [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Time to wake up!"];
  [localNotification setSoundName:@"Thunder Song.m4r"];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Here are two `Github` link for example code or Alarm but UILocalNotification dont have any method for setting snooze :

https://github.com/retsohuang/AlarmClock

https://github.com/bauerjon/Alarm-Clock-iOS

Comment: I tried using above code. But its not showing notification.
Right now its 4:02 pm

The date i am passing is :-  2015-09-17 16:05:00 +0000

But its not showing notification.

Comment: you need to more research on this new demo that code is correct check the setting time https://github.com/eliotfowler/awake

Comment: Will it play the sound even if the device is on silent mode?