# How to play a sound with AVAudioPlayer every Monday using Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I play a sound with AVAudioPlayer every Monday using Swift?

I have an AVAudioPlayer setup and ready to play a sound at a specific time.

My issue is that when I select which weekday (2 = monday) that I would like to have my sound play and repeat every time the current weekday matches the selected weekday and convert this to DateComponents I need to get the day, month, and year from the selectedDateTime when these field are not needed because I only care about having this sound repeat every week at the selected weekday.  If I do not provide the day, month, year the sound will not play and the timeInterval become negative.

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: selectedDateTime)
                dateComponents.minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: selectedDateTime)
                dateComponents.timeZone = .current
                dateComponents.weekday = 2

// should not be needed (below)
                dateComponents.day = calendar.component(.day, from: selectedDateTime)
                dateComponents.month = calendar.component(.month, from: selectedDateTime)
                dateComponents.year = calendar.component(.year, from: selectedDateTime)
```

What will allow me to schedule and play an AVAudioPlayer every monday?

Please note that I am intending the user to keep the app open in the background.

Comment: What are you scheduling these DateComponents with? I assume UNCalendarNotificationTrigger? (I wouldn't think you can do what you're trying to do with an AVAudioPlayer. Typically you would use a UNNotificationSound for this.) For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627322/play-alarm-sound-when-app-is-not-running-ios/32627681#32627681

Comment: How do you wish to play the sound? Every time user opens the app there will be a sound or you want to play the sound on Monday irrespective whether the app is open or not.

Comment: I would like to play the sound when it is monday, but only if the app is open.  Please note that this functionality will need to work even if the user keeps the app open for let's say a week.

Comment: Also I am not using UNCalendarNotificationTrigger because I believe this is best used with notifications.  Here I am not trying to use a notification.